# Is it possible to push up a detached head in git as a rollback strategy?

Tags: git, github

We are looking into a potential rollback strategy for master and Im wondering if it's possible?

Let's say there is a bug at the tip of master and development

```
dev 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG 
                     |
                   HEAD
master 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG 
                     |
                   HEAD
```

I would like to change the head of master back a commit but keep the git history (this is the rollback since master would no longer have the bug)

```
dev 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG 
                     |
                   HEAD
master 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG 
               |
              HEAD
```

We then fix the change on dev

```
dev 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG -- FIX
                            |
                           HEAD
master 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG 
               |
              HEAD
```

and then we do a fast forward git merge to get the fix to master and the HEAD back to the correct location:

```
dev 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG -- FIX
                            |
                           HEAD
master 
A -- B -- C -- D -- BUG -- FIX
                            |
                           HEAD
```

Im wondering is if it's possible to detach the head on master and keep the history like Im describing? and if so how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you'd put your commands in each step.

Comment: Not really sure I understand the issue.  If both dev and master are at `BUG`, then just do: `git checkout master; git reset --hard ${D_SHA}; git checkout dev; # fix stuff; git commit -m "fix stuff"; git checkout master; git reset --hard dev`(But I don't really see the point of resetting master back one commit.  It doesn't seem that accomplishes much of anything)

Comment: @williamPursell thanks for the response! If you reset master back a commit it would no longer be on the commit with the bug (thus not have the bug in the code)

Comment: @williamPursell The only problem I can think of with that is it will require a force push to get the changes back to origin. I was hoping there was a way around turning on force push access for our protected branches. And to be fair, I didn't mention this in the main issue.

Comment: If you want to avoid a force push, I would say create `D'` which reverts BUG, push it, then create a new commit that fixes it.  This leaves BUG in the history which will make future bisects difficult, but that's the price for avoiding a force push.

Comment: The statement "detach the HEAD on master" makes no sense if by "master" you mean a branch. Because detaching a HEAD is done on a file tree and leaves the branch. You can keep some folder in a detached state for a while, but likely this is not what you want and you are confusing git concepts.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, there are a couple ways you could do this:

1. Create a fix branch at the current state, then reset the main branch to the previous commit. You can then merge the fix branch back into the main branch.
2. Check out the earlier ref (commit hash) and branch there as a history record.

Answer (score 1):

while i think that isherwood's answer is correct, here's another tip if you want to avoid rolling back history with a force-push:

- revert the buggy-commit in `master` (so now master doesn't have the bug anymore)

  ```
  git revert HEAD~1
  ```
- branch off your develop-branch from the new master, and revert the reversion

  ```
  git checkout -b fix-bug
  git revert HEAD~1
  ```
- fix the bug in the `fix-bug` branch
- merge it back into `master` (or fast-forward, depending on your needs):

  ```
  git checkout master
  git merge fix-bug
  ```